# Private method invoking from outside the class in Java

Tags: java, class, private-methods, private-constructor

I have one class with private method now i want to access that private method outside the class, which is possible using reflection package in java.
    But what if we make class constructor as private, then how to access that method. In below code consider that PrivateMethodClass is having private method m1 and private constructor.

```
package allprograms;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class RecursionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try 
         {

            PrivateMethodClass p = PrivateMethodClass.getInstance();
            //Class c = Class.forName("allprograms.PrivateMethodClass");  //1 
            Class c = Class.class.asSubclass(p.getClass());
            //Object o = c.newInstance();                                   //2
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("m1", null);                 //3
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(p, null);                                          //4

        } /*
             * catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { //for 1
             * System.out.println("ClassNotFound"); }
             */catch (IllegalAccessException/* | InstantiationException */e) { // for 2
            System.out.println("Illigal Access Exception or Instantiation Exception");
        } catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {  //for 3 
            System.out.println("No such Method Exception e");
        } catch(Exception e) {   //for 4
            System.out.println("Invocation Target Exception ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it out? Why not implement it and run and see how it goes? That would help you understand better and also you will never ever forget it :)

Comment: @MathewsMathai I have tried it! I have provide instance of that class using factory method, u can see it in this line //PrivateMethodClass p = PrivateMethodClass.getInstance();

Comment: But this doesnt work further. May be answer to my question is that its impossible to called private method outside if containing class in singleton class

Comment: Grab the constructor via [`Class#getDeclaredConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), make the constructor accessible & create the instance via [`Constructor#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: Is static method `getInstance()` in class `PrivateMethodClass` a public method?

Comment: @VinceEmigh we have object using factory method, now i just want to invoke that private method.

Comment: @Abra , it is a static method, as it is a **factory method**.

Comment: Yes, `getInstance()` is a static method. That's obvious from the code you posted. What access modifier does the method have? Is it a `public` method?

Comment: @Abra oops. sorry i didnt get it at first. and yes. it is a public method.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, Thank you so much! You already suggested the correct answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your issue is. Static method `getInstance()` in class `PrivateMethodClass` is public so no problem to call it, which means it doesn't matter if the constructor of `PrivateMethodClass` is *private* or not.

If, on the other hand, you are asking how to instantiate class `PrivateMethodClass` ***without*** using method `getInstance()`, this is also not a problem. Just as you use `getDeclaredMethod()` to invoke (*private*) method `m1()`, you can call method [getDeclaredConstructor()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to get a reference to the *private* constructor. Example code follows:

```java
Class<?> c = PrivateMethodClass.class;
try {
    Constructor<?> ctor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
    ctor.setAccessible(true);
    Object obj = ctor.newInstance();
    System.out.println(obj);
    if (obj instanceof PrivateMethodClass) {
        PrivateMethodClass p = (PrivateMethodClass) obj;
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("m1");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(p);
    }
}
catch (Exception x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am I missing something?